# TFS Build..Deploy vs Release

Tags: tfs, build, devops

I have web applications that we build using build scripts and deploy as the last step of those build scripts, if everything builds and unit tests pass. We deploy to staging area.

With the new Release management functionality in TFS, Should I move the Deploy task from the build definition to the Release area? The Release Definition seems to only be able to copy files versus a build script can update an application running in IIS.

I honestly at this point do not see the need for the Release Management in TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Release Management is used to be an independent tool of TFS.

[image]

It has been integrated into Azure Pipelines and Team Foundation Server (TFS)as web-based version in TFS 2015 Update 2 and above or Azure Pipelines.

Release Management not only be able to copy files versus a build script but also as a Continuous Delivery (CD). It is a process by which code is built, tested, and deployed to **one or more test and production environments**. Deploying and testing in multiple environments drives quality.

CI(build) systems produce the deployable artifacts including infrastructure and apps. Automated release processes consume these artifacts to release new versions and fixes to existing systems. Monitoring and alerting systems run continually to drive visibility into the entire CD process. The Release service in TFS helps you set up and manage CD for your applications.

[image]

As for the difference on Release Management vs deploy task at the end of build pipeline, you could also take a look at this similar question: [TFS Release Management vs build deploy task at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363167/tfs-release-management-vs-build-deploy-task-at-the-end)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I doubt the majority of people that are not on Azure are using release management. I bet they are using publish profiles with build scripts. If I were MS I would phase out publish profiles if the intent is to get people to publish using CI/CD